# Difference between 以前 and 前 to indicate past time?

Tags: word-choice, usage, difference

I wanted to express in Mandarin:

> Three months ago I started yoga classes.

I thought about whether to use 前 or 以前 to express "ago":

> 三个月**以前**我开始了上瑜伽课。
>
> Sān gè yuè **yǐqián** wǒ kāishǐ le shàng yújiā kè.

> 三个月**前**我开始了上瑜伽课。
>
> Sān gè yuè **qián** wǒ kāishǐ le shàng yújiā kè.

Is there a difference between both sentences? Is there a preference between 前 or 以前? If that is the case, what are the general rules behind?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say the more important difference is the one [between 以前 and 之前](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/1263/25265)。The difference between 以前 and 前 follows from it.

(Bonus 1: to do yoga is better rendered with 练瑜伽)

(Bonus 2: to me, the sentence sounds better with a modal 了, as 开始 semantics inherently convey a change. native speakers might expand on this)

**之前** expresses anteriority in time **relative to something else**. It can be used when describing event sequences in a time different than the present. It can be translated in English with "*earlier, prior to*".

> 三个月之前我开始练瑜伽（了）
>
> Three months earlier, I (had) started doing yoga (relative to another given time)

**以前** expresses anteriority **relative to the present**. It can be translated with "*ago*".

> 三个月以前我开始练瑜伽（了）
>
> Three months ago, I started doing yoga (relative to the current time)

Though this distinction is quite faint. It's possible to find 之前 used just like 以前, and vice versa.

---

Now 前 alone could be an **abbreviation of either of those**, so its actual meaning is dependant on the context. Generally speaking, I would say there is no appreciable difference between 前 and 以前, except maybe that the former appears more frequently in writing.

A quick Google search:

> `site: xinhua.net "一个月前"` yields ~7000 results
>
> `site: xinhua.net "一个月以前"` yields ~3000 results

This is empirically true also for other combinations. Another example:

> `site: xinhua.net "一年前"` yields ~65k results
>
> `site: xinhua.net "一年以前"` yields ~3300 results

Comment: But isn't the action of "started attending a yoga class" completed?

Comment: in this sentence, the focus tends to be on the change/beginning of something, which is also inherent in the semantics of 开始, so the modal 了 (change) is more appropriate than the aspect 了 (completeness of an action).

Comment: Ok! So both the aspect 了 and the modal 了 can be omitted? If we included the modal 了, it would just emphasize the change of state?

Comment: I would say the sentence is passable without modal 了 and *should be* without aspect 了。Also, let me point out that "to do yoga" is 练瑜伽

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any essential difference between your two sentences.  前 or 以前 wouldn't affect the meaning.

However, the position of 了  can be improved.  E. g.

> 三个月以前我开始上了瑜伽课
>
> 三个月前我开始上了瑜伽课

or

> 三个月以前我开始上瑜伽课了
>
> 三个月前我开始上瑜伽课了

You can also put 三个月以前 in the middle(after the subject 我):

> 我三个月以前开始上了瑜伽课。

If you want to be more factual, you can put:

> 我三个月前开始上的瑜伽课。

Comment: What's that 的 doing in your last sentence?

Comment: @Pedroski I just noticed recently that this use of 的 is not recognized by many people.  In my example, you can take it as the 是. .. 的. ... structure with 是 being omitted. like 我是三个月前开始上的瑜伽课。

Comment: Why is it better to write 了 after 上 instead of after 开始? I thought the action that is completed is "to start [attending class]" but not "attending class", which still is currently happening.

Comment: @Puco4 We take 开始xxx as a whole to mean "to start to do something".  E. g.  开始玩皮球。 We don't usually seperate it.

Answer (score 1):

I think 以前 can be used as a word on its own and only refers to some unspecified time in the past, whereas 前 needs an accompanying phrase like 几天/几年 and has meanings not always associated with time.

Three months ago I started yoga classes.
我三个月前开始上瑜伽课。
三个月前我开始上瑜伽课。
Not so nice without a time:
*前我开始上瑜伽课。

前几天我碰到你丈夫了。
I ran into your hubby a few days ago.

以前我碰到过你丈夫。
I met your hubby before.

Answer (score 1):

三个月**以前**我开始了上瑜伽课

三个月**前**我开始了上瑜伽课

三个月**之前**我开始了上瑜伽课

these three sentences have the same meaning.

三个月以前我**开始了上瑜伽课** => 三个月以前我**开始上瑜伽课了** or 三个月以前我**开始了瑜伽课** is more fluent.